# R Wide to long format for multiple variables with patterns

Tags: r, melt

I have a data set with a single identifier and five columns that repeat 18 times. I want to restructure the data into long format keeping the first five column headings as the column headings. Below is a sample with just two repeats:

```
structure(list(Response.ID = 1:2, Task = structure(c(1L, 1L), .Label = "task1", class = "factor"), 
Freq = structure(c(1L, 1L), .Label = "Daily", class = "factor"), 
Hours = c(3L, 2L), Value = c(10L, 8L), Mood = structure(1:2, .Label = c("Engaged", 
"Neutral"), class = "factor"), Task.1 = structure(c(1L, 1L
), .Label = "task2", class = "factor"), Freq.1 = structure(c(1L, 
1L), .Label = "Weekly", class = "factor"), Hours.1 = c(4L, 
4L), Value.1 = c(10L, 6L), Mood.1 = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("Neutral", 
"Optimistic"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Response.ID", "Task", "Freq", "Hours", "Value", "Mood", "Task.1", "Freq.1", "Hours.1", "Value.1", "Mood.1"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

I attempted using the melt and patterns functions, which appears to approximate my desired outcome without the desired column headings:

```
df = melt(df1, id.vars = c("Response.ID"), measure.vars = patterns("^Task", "^Freq","^Hours","^Mood"))
```

Here is the result:

```
structure(list(Response.ID = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), class = "factor", .Label = c("1", "2")), value1 = c("task1", "task1", "task2", "task2"), value2 = c("Daily", "Daily", "Weekly", "Weekly"), value3 = c(3L, 2L, 4L, 4L), value4 = c("Engaged", "Neutral", "Optimistic", "Neutral")), .Names = c("Response.ID", "variable", "value1", "value2", "value3", "value4"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000330788>)
```

When I tried to specify names with value.name() below I receive an error:

```
df = melt(df1, id.vars = c("Response.ID"),measure.vars = patterns("^Task", "^Freq","^Hours","^Mood"), value.name=c("Task", "Freq", "Hours", "Value","Mood"))
```

My desired result would look like this:

```
structure(list(Response.ID = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), Task = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("task1", "task2"), class = "factor"), 
Freq = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Daily", "Weekly"
), class = "factor"), Hours = c(3L, 2L, 4L, 4L), Value = c(10L, 
8L, 10L, 6L), Mood = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("Engaged", 
"Neutral", "Optimistic"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Response.ID", "Task", "Freq", "Hours", "Value", "Mood"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you embarked on a difficult journey by using `melt`: this function is well named in the sense that trying to use it will probably melt your brain. Joke aside, the function `melt` has lots of underlying computations and its use could be inefficient if you have a large dataset.

I would instead solve the problem manually with `rbindlist` (from the excellent package `data.table`, which also ships with an optimized version of `melt` if you really want to use it), to manually concatenates groups of columns. This also preserves the column names:

```
> rbindlist(lapply(1:2, function(i) df1[,c(1,((i-1)*5+2):((i-1)*5+6))]))
   Response.ID  Task   Freq Hours Value       Mood
1:           1 task1  Daily     3    10    Engaged
2:           2 task1  Daily     2     8    Neutral
3:           1 task2 Weekly     4    10 Optimistic
4:           2 task2 Weekly     4     6    Neutral
```

This works on your example: replace the indices `1:2` by the number of repetitions to make it work with the real dataset (so, `lapply(1:18)`).

Comment: This works perfectly on the larger data file and it's very quick.